How to fix the following deprecated issue faced on WordPress website: Deprecated

Deprecated: preg_split(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($subject) of type string is deprecated in /home/(directy of page)/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 3506

The link texts popus in wordpress editor and on our website ,
possible believe could be since we upgraded the php version from 5.3 to 8.1
Please let me know what can help

thats quite a jump from 5.3 to 8 version. Prob you have tones of errors and you need to make your theme compatible with modern versions. Make a backup and update everything and start fixing i guess..
